Is there a Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition for fields?
is there a Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition avaliable for Fields and not for particles?
for example for particles we have that $ n_i h = \oint p_i.dq_i .$
but the same for Fields with a field $ \Psi (x,t) $ and momentum $ \Pi_\Psi .$

When you are going so deep as to be all the way to fields, why would you want an inferior quantisation condition?

Quantum fields are essentially mere elaborate arrangements/repackagings of an infinity of quantized harmonic oscillators.
